# Is there a way to ignore zero length files while reading avro to rdd?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a folder in hdfs with sources for my spark job. Some of the files have zero length size, so I get: `IOExeption: Not an Avro data file`. If I remove them everything is working fine, is there a way to ignore them?

The way I read Avro to rdd in Java:

```
JavaPairRDD<AvroWrapper<GenericRecord>, NullWritable> pairRDD =
        (JavaPairRDD<AvroWrapper<GenericRecord>, NullWritable>)sc.hadoopFile(inputPath, AvroInputFormat.class, AvroWrapper.class, NullWritable.class);
```